# Primefaces colocar Filtro no rodapé ao invés do cabeçalho

Tags: primefaces

Neste exemplo podemos ver que o filterby adiciona o filtro no header e eu gostaria de colocar no footer.

Alguém saberia como fazer ou até mesmo tenha utilizado?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

Comment: Luídne havia respondido aqui mas excluiu e eu acho que é isso mesmo: *"Você pode adicionar o atributo filterPosition="bottom" na sua coluna <p:column>."*

Comment: Infelizmente o filterPosition, posiciona o filtro apenas abaixo ou acima do headerText e não no footer da coluna.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar o facet do prime dentro da tag footer, tipo assim:

```
<footer>
  <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:outputText value="Pesquisar por: " />
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('widgetVarDaSuaTabela').filter()" style="width:150px" placeholder="Digite aqui"/>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>
</footer>
```